# Calling push method on array crashes after object is updated with Object.assign

Tags: javascript, typescript

We receive JSON from the network and we are converting the data into the objects of the classes we have in TypeScript so the getter and setters work, like in the example below

```
class Sent {
  id: number

  constructor(model? : Sent){
    if(model){
      Object.assign(this, model);
    }
  }
}

class Email{
  name: string;
  age: number;
  sent: Sent[];

  constructor(model?: Email){
    if(model){
      Object.assign(this, model);
      for(let x of model.sent){
        this.sent.push(new Sent(x))
       }
    }
  }
}
```

When we create a new object using the JSON data like in the example below, the browser crashes on the line `this.sent.push(new Sent(x))`.

If we replace `push` with `concat` it works fine.

If we set `this.sent` to new empty array before the loop, like this `this.sent = []`, then it works too

Just trying to understand why `push` method crashes here. Any help is appreciated

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ffh7ya) to recreate the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `Object.assign(this, model);` you simply bind two objects together (as long as javascript objects are passed by reference). See this code for explanation:

```js
obj1 = {}
obj2 = {list: []}
Object.assign(obj1, obj2);
obj2.list.push(1);
console.log(obj1.list);
```

So, after adding element to the property of second object it appears in the first one.

Let's get back to your question. You've binded `this` and `model` objects. Iterating over `model.send` property you are pushing elements to `this.sent` which is actually the same as if you'd push elements to `model.send`. Thus you get an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise, using `this.sent.concat(new Sent(x));` you don’t change anything due to
`concat` method creates a new array consisting of the elements from both arrays that is returned. So, in your case, after  `Object.assign(this, model);` there is already `Object{"id":23}` in `sent` property that returns and `this.sent.concat(new Sent(x))` just is instruction that do nothing.